# Should I draft leaders or bid for houses first in Lorenzo Il Magnifico?

Tags: expansions

I'm playing with the Houses of Reinassance expansion. The manual isn't too clear on whether leader drafting comes before house bidding or not. The wording states something like:

1. Leader drafting is done during preparation
2. House bidding is done before the first round

From this wording we've concluded leader drafting comes first, but we're unsure, and I haven't been able to find an FAQ so far.

Comment: What do you mean by 'House Bidding'?  this isn't a term used in the rules.   The word 'House'. is only used in an example as text on a card.  https://cmon-files.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/assets_item/resource/49/Rulebook_LorenzoIlMagnifico.pdf

Comment: @StartPlayer I'm referring to the Houses of Renaissance expansion rules

Comment: Ah that wasn't clear to me from the question.  Probably worth editing to say that then.  I've not played the expansion, just base game, which is probably why I didn't recognise the term.

Answer (score 1):

In [the base game rules](https://cmon-files.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/assets_item/resource/49/Rulebook_LorenzoIlMagnifico.pdf) advanced set up players are instructed to take a personal bonus tile and then draft leaders.

In [the expansion rules](https://cmon-files.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/assets_item/resource/135/LRZ002-Rules-web.pdf) auction for the Family Tiles is listed before drafting leaders.  This auction also gives players their start resources.  in base game starting resources are also done before drafting leaders.

Whilst I agree that 'before the first round' could be read both ways I would go 'Family Tiles' and then 'Leader drafting' as the instruction to add new leaders is not given until after the auction in the rules.